# Problem with character vectors and linear regression in R

Tags: r, regression, modeling, software

Quick question.

I want to perform a linear regression that looks like this:

```
lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 +x5, mydata)
```

This works fine if I manually write out this code.

However, the independent variables that I want to use are stored as a character, like this:

```
> vars
[1] "x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 +x5"
```

I tried typing this:

```
lm(y ~ vars, mydata)
Error in model.frame.default...
```

But it gives an error!

So then I tried this:

```
lm(y ~ noquote(vars), mydata)
Error in model.frame.default...
```

And then this

```
lm(y ~ print(vars, quote = FALSE), mydata)
Error in model.frame.default...
```

Anyone have a clue how I can get around this problem? The character string in "vars" is being provided to me by a program upstream, so I can't work around it at that level.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you have access to x1,...,x5? I do not get this "x1+...+x5" representation.

Comment: Yes, but I just put them there as placeholders as an example. They are just variables. I have thousands of variables in my database, so writing this code by hand is not possible.

Comment: @Xi'an Alexander has a character string representing the RHS of a model formula in R. The problem then is how to create a valid R formula from this character string representation.

Comment: +1 From me - clear question with simple example and evidence of effort in trying to solve the problem. Not sure why this was down-voted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can build a formula from character vectors using standard R functions and `as.formula()`. The trick is to note that you need to have a full formula (containing at least a `~`) for R to create a formula object for you. Here is an example

```
## predictors
vars <- "x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5"

## dummy data for example
dat <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(120), ncol = 6))
names(dat) <- c("y", paste("x", 1:5, sep = ""))

## create a formula - here we need to paste on the response part
##  y ~
form <- as.formula(paste("y ~", vars))

## Fit the model using `form`
mod <- lm(form, data = dat)
```

If you print `form` you'll see that R has created a special object that no longer prints as a character string would:

```
> form
y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5
```

Comment: Gavin, thanks a ton for your help! This is the first time that I've come across the "as.formula()" function - quite useful!